# How can I push a new list onto the root view side of a split view controller?

Tags: uiview, push, uisplitviewcontroller, rootview

I am trying to push a new list into the root view side of the split view controller on an iPad app based on what the user selects in the root view table.  For some reason I cannot figure out how to push a new array - or listview onto the left side.

Help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply has a navigationController and you call self.navigationController and push the new view on top of it.  Simple!